# Как изменить фразу, чтобы вместо тире стояла запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика

1) Деревья гибнут — лес не умирает.

2) Земля кругла — на ней не скроешь тайны.

Answer (score 1):

*Как переделать предложения, чтобы вместо тире стояла запятая?*

Можно в обоих предложениях употребить предлоги, перед которыми нужно ставить запятую:

1) **Деревья гибнут, *но* лес не умирает**;

2)  **Земля кругла, *поэтому* на ней не скроешь тайны.**

Comment: А если без союзов, то как тогда?

Comment: Деревья гибнут, лес умирает?

Comment: По-другому (без добавления предлогов) фразу изменить невозможно, не меняя её смысл. Допустимо, в конце концов, просто поставить запятые вместо тире. Но Вы-то говорите именно об изменении фразы.

Comment: 1) деревья гибнут, лес - не умирает 2) Земля кругла, на ней не скроешь тайны. Элементарно, Ватсон... хотя смысл 2 фразы без предлога слегка меняется

Answer (score 0):

1) **Деревья гибнут, не умирает лес.** Сравнить: Дорог не подарок, дорого внимание.

Значение **несоответствия при наличии отрицательной частицы НЕ** можно выразить при постановке запятой (без увеличенных пауз, характерных для  тире и двоеточия). Но нужна **перестройка структуры,** интонация в таких случаях нисходяще-нисходящая, то есть полное понижение голоса в конце каждой части.

2) **Земля кругла, на ней не скроешь тайны.** Здесь запятая даже более уместна, вторая часть **распространяет** первую (на неоднородность/взаимообусловленность частей предложения указывает такой структурный элемент, как **местоимение "на ней".**